# give an example of polynomials $f,g,h \in \mathbb{Q}[x] - \{0\}$ such that $f^2 + g^3 = h ^6$

Tags: number-theory

give an example of polynomials $f,g,h \in \mathbb{Q}[x] - \{0\}$, not all constant such that:

$f^2 + g^3 = h ^6, \gcd(f,g,h) = 1$

I have proven that in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, with $\gcd(f,g,h) = 1$, this is not possible but i don't see how to choose such polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that this is true....?

Kees

Comment: how did you prove that in $\mathbb Z[x]$ it is not possible?

Comment: with mason stohers theorem.

Comment: You can use it also for $\mathbb Q[x]$. Why should such polynomials exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually is possible even in $\Bbb Z[x]$:

$(3x^3)^2+(-2x^2)^3=x^6$

Comment: yeah, in Z[x] one extra restriction i got was that the $gcd(f,g,h) = 1$. Suppose we have that restriction here as well is it still possible?

Kees